# Istio egress rules to access services directly

Tags: kubernetes, istio

In the guide https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress.html, there is a way to access non-http traffic by includingIPRanges. However, when I follow the instructions I still am unable to access anything. Should this rule allow me to bypass istio for egress as I think it should or am I missing something?

I run a version of this command

kubectl apply -f <(istioctl kube-inject -f samples/sleep/sleep.yaml --includeIPRanges=172.30.0.0/16,172.20.0.0/16,10.10.10.0/24) is the command it suggests for bluemix users, but this does not work for me. When I try to store from my app in cloud object store I get a 500 error, however with no istio sidecar the store function works perfectly.

Comment: What error do you get? - Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46976349/istio-egress-rules-to-access-services-directly#) your question to include the command you posted in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me using Istio 0.2.10 on a Bluemix free tier cluster. Are you saying that the egress task doesn't even work for you, i.e., you can't do the curl suggested in the task?

`kubectl exec -it $SOURCE_POD -c sleep curl http://httpbin.org/headers`

A 500 error doesn't sound like a problem related to reach-ability anyway. That sounds like the server you're calling is crashing?

Comment: I can reach the application, see certain parts of it, but when I try to call cloud object store using my api on a Kubernetes cluster with istio I get a 500 error. The same thing without istio installed gives no error, and works as expected. Egress was my best guess but it may be something else, however it is certainly istio related.